# Formulating json array

Tags: json, post, erlang, ejabberd

I am trying to fire a httpc request.

```
httpc:request(post, {Baseurl,[{"Authorization",ApiKey2}],<<"application/json">>,Body},[],[]).
```

But when i pass try to formulate Body Which is given below :-

```
Body = lists:flatten(mochijson2:encode({struct,[{"registration_ids",[{array, "APA91bE445JOlMvdShgQAJIxuDcBQos7olZi82lWQ82W9HHTR0uxOILvDYo9F5827BhU0qpBi9xpBqN1BNciWogiWxenI7_au7Z42o6eqcFSkoAs-0tVJzVG3lju54PXRyVS1tmZNhjsQDCYwnHJH6m6j6h1vSPBZl6lt3j8tu44Euq3PyISKBM"}]},
     {"data",[{array,[{struct, [{"message","HGHJG"}]}]}]}
    ]})).
```

it gives me error like:-
mod_gcm_apns:send_gcm_msg("GJHGHJ").

```
{error,{"HTTP/1.1",
    "Field \"data\" must be a JSON array: [[{\"message\":[72,71,72,74,71]}]]\n"}}
```

tried a lot but not able to find a solution.

After making changes as suggested by mdaguete

```
% Create Json struct
  Body = lists:flatten(mochijson2:encode(
{struct,[
{<<"registration_ids">>,[<<"APA91bE445JOlMvdShgQAJIxuDcBQos7olZi82lWQ82W9HHTR0uxOILvDYo9F5827BhU0qpBi9xpBqN1BNciWogiWxenI7_au7Z42o6eqcFSkoAs-0tVJzVG3lju54PXRyVS1tmZNhjsQDCYwnHJH6m6j6h1vSPBZl6lt3j8tu44Euq3PyISKBM">>]},
 {<<"data">>,[
  {struct, [
      {<<"message">>,<<"HGHJG">>}
      ]}
     ]}
]})),
```

execution line:-

```
mod_gcm2:send_gcm_msg("JKJ").
```

But it is giving following error:

```
{error,{"HTTP/1.1",
    "JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 27.\n"}}
```

Kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: @emil:-no we basically need to send array of  json to google api so that is why we are encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Body Variable:-

```
Body = lists:flatten(mochijson2:encode(
{ struct,[
{ registration_ids,
                   ['KEY']},
{ data,[{
           message,[Message]
}
```

This is the final JSON Packet that worked with Google GCM API.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the best and fastest way to solve a problem is reading the doc.

You're using the excelent mochijson2 library from Bob Ippolito, if you [read the source](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/mochijson2.erl) code header you can read the correct format to express json in erlang terms.

The correct format for your json could be (you didn't explain the result expected):

```
{struct,[
 {<<"registration_ids">>,[<<"APA91bE445JOlMvdShgQAJIxuDcBQos7olZi82lWQ82W9HHTR0uxOILvDYo9F5827BhU0qpBi9xpBqN1BNciWogiWxenI7_au7Z42o6eqcFSkoAs-0tVJzVG3lju54PXRyVS1tmZNhjsQDCYwnHJH6m6j6h1vSPBZl6lt3j8tu44Euq3PyISKBM">>]},
 {<<"data">>,[
      {struct, [
          {<<"message">>,<<"HGHJG">>}
      ]}
 ]}
]}
```

Regards.

Comment: please refer to the edited question.Am still recieving some error.Thanks for the help